# jQuery - Get Text From Element & Add To Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm still learning jQuery - So I'm sorry if I'm asking a lot, or if what I'm asking is easy or silly.

When I have a question I usually try to give an example of what I've tried but I honestly don't know where to start!  So even some guidance on what I need to do would be more than okay!  I'm more than willing to try and do this myself, I'm just not sure what to Google!

Basically what I want to do is get content of my Anchors and add them to a tracking attribute.  And then the spaces in the attribute be swapped to +'s

**Code:**

```
<a href="#" tracking="Banner-_-Link+1-_-">LINK ONE</a>
<a href="#" tracking="Banner-_-Link+2-_-">LINK TWO</a>
```

**Code After Load**

```
<a href="#" tracking="Banner-_-Link+1-_-LINK+ONE">LINK ONE</a>
<a href="#" tracking="Banner-_-Link+2-_-LINK+TWO">LINK TWO</a>
```

Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Piece-by-piece:

Get all links with a `tracking` attribute:

```
var anchors = $('a[tracking]');
```

and loop through them:

```
anchors.each( function() {
```

at each point, get the `a` element and its text (replacing `' '` with `'+'`):

```
  var a = $(this); 
  var txt = a.text().replace(' ', '+');
```

and append that text to the existing attribute:

```
  a.attr('tracking', a.attr('tracking') + txt);
```

and we're done.

```
});
```

Example: http://codepen.io/paulroub/pen/Extrl

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!  This is exactly what I needed and you've made it really clear. Thanks Paul!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="click-this" tracking="Banner-_-Link+1-_-">LINK ONE</a> <!--Added Class 'click-this'-->
<a href="#" class="click-this" tracking="Banner-_-Link+2-_-">LINK TWO</a>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.click-this').on('click', function(){ //On click of the anchor tag
    var a = $(this).text(); //Take the text content of the one that's being clicked
    var b = $(this).attr('tracking'); //take the existing content of attribute 'tracking'
    b = b+a; //concatenating the two
    $(this).attr('tracking', b); //reassigning the new value to attribute
});
```

Read up a lot on Jquery using their docs.

Learn more about `.attr()` here: http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way is to hange your html to this:

```
 <a href="#" tracking="Banner-_-Link+1-_-" onclick=$(this).attr('tracking',$(this).attr('tracking')+$(this).text().replace(' ', '+'))>LINK ONE</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach to do it is maybe adding it to a data attribute:

```
<a href="#" data-tracking="Banner-_-Link+1-_-">LINK ONE</a>
```

You can access it by using `data` method:

```
$('a').data('tracking'); //Banner-_-Link+1-_-
```

I don't know why you want to change it on the fly, but anyway, you can..

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var anchor = $(this),
        anchorData = anchor.data('tracking'),
        text = anchor.text().replace(' ', '+');
    anchor.data('tracking', anchorData += text);
});
```

Just make sure you got the correct scope on selecting those `a` with jQuery, otherwise you will get all anchors from your page.