# Novice JQuery help needed – extract anchor text and use to define data attribute

Tags: jquery

I would like to extract text from existing anchor elements and use it to define a 'data-filter' attribute on the same anchor (where none previously existed).

The desired out come would be a script that turned this:

```
<a class="b-category-link" href="#">Exercise</a>
```

into this:

```
<a class="b-category-link" href="#" data-filter="exercise">Exercise</a>
```

I have a [codepen](http://codepen.io/voodoo6/pen/qZeeyL) that is *nearly* working, though my limited knowledge has caused me to hit a wall.

In the [codepen](http://codepen.io/voodoo6/pen/qZeeyL) (edited from [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25595968/jquery-get-text-from-element-add-to-attribute) stackoverflow question), you can see that the JQuery is successfully extracting the anchor text (the CSS is used to show the output of the script and display it in red), but the script is adding an *'undefined'* value too which I need removing. Can anybody help me understand where this is being generated from and how to edit the script to remove it?

Many thanks for any advice.

http://codepen.io/voodoo6/pen/qZeeyL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute

```
  a.attr("data-filter", txt);
```

for

```
  a.attr("data-filter", a.attr("data-filter") + txt);
```

Comment: @matt_50 Note also, only one `::after` pseudo-element declaration is necessary at `css`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will never work, because the js is executed after css.
Try adding the property first then push the css properties.